# Evaluating expressions

Tags: erlang

I'm doing some past-papers and need to know if I am correct here.

Give step-by-step evaluations of the following expressions:

```
foo(0,[2,3,1])
foo(0,[4,0,1])
```

where foo is defined like this:

```
foo(_,[]) -> [];
foo(Y,[X|_]) when X==Y -> [X];
foo(Y,[X|Xs]) -> [X | foo(Y,Xs) ].
```

My answers:

1.

```
Foo(0, [2, 3, 1])
[2 | foo(0, 3, 1) ]
[2, 3| foo(0, 1) ]
[2, 3, 1 | foo (0)]
[2, 3, 1]
```

2.

```
Foo(0, [4, 0, 1])
[4 | foo(0, 0,1])
[4, 0]
```

Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1):

At least the function parameter are wrong, I would say:

```
1.

foo(0,[2,3,1])
[2|foo(0,[3,1])]        % 3rd clause
[2|[3|foo(0,[1])]]      % 3rd clause
[2|[3|[1|foo(0,[])]]]   % 3rd clause
[2|[3|[1|[]]]]          % 1st clause
[2,3,1]

2.

foo(0,[4,0,1])
[4|foo(0,[0,1])]        % 3rd clause
[4|[0]]                 % 2nd clause
[4, 0]
```

Comment: What would you say this function does? I've got it as removing all instances of 'Y'. In this case all zero elements.

Comment: foo(Elem,List) returns a copy of List where all elements after Elem are dropped.